# Getting error #1064 when trying to drop foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to drop the foreign key from the table `pcwithhw`. But It shows the error:-

> :#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`hw_serial_no`' at line 2

Following querying I am trying to run.

```
alter table pcwithhw
drop foreign key fk_`hw_serial_no`;
```

Any clue relevant to the problem????

Answer (score 1):

The `fk_` prefix forms part of the foreign key name: it must therefore either be included within the quotes, or else the quotes should be removed entirely.  That is:

```
alter table pcwithhw
drop foreign key `fk_hw_serial_no`;
```

or

```
alter table pcwithhw
drop foreign key fk_hw_serial_no;
```

As it stands you have the backtick character appearing in the middle of an unquoted name, which gives rise to the syntax error that you observe (MySQL parses the backtick as the start of a new, invalid, token).

Comment: When i run your suggested query without backtick or using backtick for fk too then getting following error:-
#1025 - Error on rename of '.\bl_pc_record\pcwithhw' to '.\bl_pc_record\#sql2-19b0-17' (errno: 152)


Here bl_pc_record is my database

Comment: @NituDhaka: It sounds as though there is no foreign key constraint named `fk_hw_serial_no`.

Comment: the foreign key is hw_serial_no. And if your next solution is to remove fk_. then i also has been try it.

Comment: @NituDhaka: How have you determined that `hw_serial_no` is the name of the foreign key constraint (I suggest looking at the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE pcwithhw` - perhaps [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18826640/edit) to include a copy for our review)?

Answer (score 0):

Move the backtick the the front of the foreign key name, eg.

> `fk_hw_serial_no`